# Affect curves with wind force field?

Tags: physics, eevee-render-engine, bezier-curves, force-fields

I have grass that Ive made individually from tapered curves here, and I want apply a gentle breeze to them. I dont see a way to apply force fields to curves though - you can make the curve itself emit a force field, but not be affected.

[image]

Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: activate the soft body option in physics option.
it should make the curved bodies affect from the wind forcefield.

convert the curve object to mesh object if u want all the options

Also I would suggest to use some deform modifiers to get the breeze effect instead of going for simulation.